# [CSS]-swap row when previewed on mobile device

Tags: html, css, responsiveness

I am not using any frameworks such as bootstrap which provides classes such as `push` or `pull` to accomplish similar to what i want to achieve. What i  want to know using basic css, can do the trick to swap elements that in desktop view comes one below another, but when viewed on mobile, that order changes.

**HTML**

```
<div id='cover'>
  <div>
    <p>This is first row</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>This is second row</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#cover div{
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

In desktop, it will show something like:

> This is first row
>
> This is second row

In mobile, it should swap and show like:

> This is second row
>
> This is first row

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use flexbox, like this (inside a media query for mobile):

```
#cover div{
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse
}
```

and `flex-direction: column`  for the desktop version

Here's a codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GZeRQq

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

Though my method does work I'd suggest using @Johannes's solution

Here's how to use it with media query.

```
  #cover {
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    #cover {
      flex-direction: column-reverse;
    }
    body {
      background: orange;
    }
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: 1001px) {
    #cover {
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    body {
      background: blue;
    }
  }
```

**Original Post:**

If you want a pure css solution your best bet (I think) is using display: table

Have a look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/qrLs1x3y/) and resizing the results box, the background will change too just so you don't miss it :-)

```css
#cover {
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
}

#cover div {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .first {
    display: table-footer-group;
  }
  .second {
    display: table-header-group;
  }
  body {
    background: orange;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 601px) {
  .first {
    display: table-header-group;
  }
  .second {
    display: table-footer-group;
  }
  body {
    background: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='cover'>
  <div class="first">
    <p>This is first row</p>
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    <p>This is second row</p>
  </div>
</div>
```